# Why does step 8 of making the bootable USB take so long for my MacBook Air?

Tags: usb, mac, system-installation, dd

I'm on my MacBook Air late 2008 model, I'm currently trying to make a bootable USB to add Ubuntu to but I have gotten to the final stage of adding the image to the disk and now it isn't doing anything and hasn't been for the past few minutes. How long does it actually take for this process to go on?

Answer (score 2):

Step 8 says:

> Execute sudo dd if=/path/to/downloaded.img of=/dev/rdiskN bs=1m
>   (replace /path/to/downloaded.img with the path where the image file is
>   located; for example, ./ubuntu.imgor ./ubuntu.dmg).
>
> Using /dev/rdisk instead of /dev/disk may be faster
>   If you see the
>   error dd: Invalid number '1m', you are using GNU dd.
>   Use the same command but replace bs=1m with bs=1M
>   If you see the error dd:
>   /dev/diskN: Resource busy, make sure the disk is not in use. Start the
>   'Disk Utility.app' and unmount (don't eject) the drive

If the command has yet to end, this means that it is still writing into your USB drive. Be patient. The above `dd` command does not have a progressbar and this can be frustrating, but it has never failed me to finally end the writing.